# How to access state of some other component using Redux in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, react-redux

I have two components at same level of hierarchy.
Eg:

```
             _B
Component A /
            \_C
```

I need to access state values of B in C using redux. 
How is it possible.
PS: Yes, I can store common state values in parent A. But I'd like to use redux here. My understanding is you can access any components state using redux since it is managed at the top component level. 
Any way I can directly access store in the component or in the action ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got you question correctly but as you said, Redux maintains the store at top component level and so the store is easily available to all child components. Infact that's how you use Redux.

You can either create connected components using the connect decorator and pass whatever props you want from your store to your component. Example.

```
/* This is your container component */
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  your actions go here
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state, //pass this if you want to pass entire state
  ...any props that you want to pass
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Your view component) //this basically connects your actions and state to your view component
```

If you don't want to create any connected component and would like to access the store directly in your View component then you can access it in your constructor from context. Example.

```
class Example extends React.Component{
 constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    //access your store like this
    var store = context.store;
  }
}

//You can define the context needed for your component like this
Example.contextTypes = {
 store: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are using Redux and have defined your store at App(topmost) level then yes, this context will be available across all components.

Comment: I am not sure if context is something one must use too much in the application as it works reverse the way react work flow works. Isn't it @codeslayer1?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Yes. You should avoid directly accessing the context because in Redux, store flows from top level component to bottom using Provider and that's the reason connect decorator was provided. So that you can cherry pick the parts of store needed by any component and only pass those props instead of passing around the entire store.

Comment: That's why I feel redux's way of providing one the access to store variables is the best way instead of using context.

Comment: I dint go with 'context', I eventually went with following the react's way. I maintained all the states in the higher order parent component.

Comment: @informer Can you please accept the answer if it worked for you? And in case you need any other help or are interested in tech related discussions, you can join my Slack group here - https://join.slack.com/t/code-slayers-den/shared_invite/enQtMjQxNzM4MzQwMTk0LTVmYzcxZDQxMzliNmEyMmNjZjVmMWNhN2Q0ODkwOWZhMjBmOTA3NWFiN2JmOTY4MzhhODhlMTU4ZTM5NmMxZDI

Answer (score -1):

*UPDATE* --
The questioner wanted to use context with Redux. I misunderstood the question. I'm not confident about that specific topic, so I'll quote FB React documentation.

"If you aren't familiar with state management libraries like Redux or MobX, don't use context. For many practical applications, these libraries and their React bindings are a good choice for managing state that is relevant to many components.

**It is far more likely that Redux is the right solution to your problem than that context is the right solution.**
...

If you insist on using context despite these warnings, **try to isolate your use of context to a small area and avoid using the context API directly when possible so that it's easier to upgrade when the API changes**."

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: Where is the answer to my question here? Do you have any better way to access siblings store data other than context ?

Comment: Sorry, when you said "Any way I can directly access store in the component or in the action ?" I thought you're asking how to use connect() in Redux. I was just trying to help, but you didn't use the word context in your question :(